# How to remove R package that has dependencies on other packages?

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I've installed a R package (PathRanker) that depends on packages (xml,Rgraphviz,Rcurl). I've noticed that the all the packages' folders inside the library shows some sort of a locked sign. 
I tried to remove PathRanker using the R CMD REMOVE but it didnt works. I tried to reinstall the package (which I kindda mess around with the code) it also didnt works. So I think it got something to do with the dependency packages. Can someone help me? thanks...

Comment: Close any open R session.  That should unlock the other package directories.

Comment: yeah i manage to unlock all of them..but still i cant install the package that i modified..or there are other ways i can edit the source code without having to rebuild the package each time i modified? i mean maybe i can edit within the installed package?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Have you tried remove.packages()? If you're modifying certain functions from a package, I would advise you to create new .R files and source() those. Assuming differences are minor or cosmetic. For bigger messing with the packages, you should rebuild from source, I would guess?

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed the packages as root (if you are using Linux), and trying to remove the package as normal user.

Start an R session as root (sudo R), and try to remove (see: `?remove.packages`) the packages in this environment. Or from console:`sudo R CMD REMOVE (package name)`

If still not working, please write more about the error messages.